# Scrape phone specs from Kimovil.com

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

## Problem statement

I'm working on scraping the technical data on a number of phones from [**Kimovil**](https://www.kimovil.com/en/).
I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73218735/21414252), but this only gives access to the phone's prices. Is there a similar json webpage that gathers the technical data, i.e. everything shown on for example [this Kimovil webpage](https://www.kimovil.com/en/where-to-buy-google-pixel-7)?

I have found an alternative (summarised below) but it's quite lengthy and complex... any other solutions welcome!

## My solution

So far what I have done is:

### 1. Kimovil organisation

- Define the organisation of the data in Kimovil in a json file

```json
{
    "Technical sheet": {
        "Release Date": {
            "Release date": "Release date"
        }
    },
    "Design & Materials": {
        "Structure": {
            "Size": "Dimensions [mm]",
            "Weight": "Weight [g]",
            "Usable surface": "Screen ratio [%]",
            "Materials": "Materials"
        },
        "Screen": {
            "Diagonal": "Screen size [in]"
        }
    },
...
```

- then read it to `data_orga`
- "adapt" it to the specific phone (on Kimovil, the sections are called for example "Technical sheet of Google Pixel 7")

### 2. get webpage html content using python requests:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get("https://www.kimovil.com/en/where-to-buy-google-pixel-7")
```

### 3. Searching and saving the data

Iterate through the sections, subsections, etc using BeautifulSoup and extract the relevant data:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

# Dict where I store the information, (in the end will have eg. data["Weight [g]"] = "197 g")
data = {}

# Iterate through the sections
sections = self.soup.find_all("section", class_="kc-container")
  for section in sections:
    section_name = section.get("aria-label")

    if section_name not in data_orga:
      continue  # next section

    # Iterate throught the subsections
    subsections = section.find_all("h3", class_="k-h4")
    for subsection in subsections:
      subsection_name = subsection.get_text(strip=True)

      if subsection_name not in data_orga[section_name]:
        continue  # next subsection

      # Find the table directly after the subsection
      table = subsection.find_next("table", class_="k-dltable")
      
      # Iterate through the tags
      tags = table.find_all(delim1)
      for tag in tags:
        tag_name = tag.get_text(strip=True)

        if tag_name not in data_orga[section_name][subsection_name]:
          continue  # next tag
        
        # Get the information
        content = tag.find_next(delim2)
        info = content.get_text(strip=True)
        
        # Save the description in the data dict
        info_name = self.data_orga[section_name][subsection_name][tag_name]
        data[info_name] = info
```

### Challenges

The fact that some of the subsections are delimited by `<h3>` and others by `<div>` makes it more complex. Similarly, the subsection about the main camera is called "Double/Triple/Quad rear camera" which also complicates the searching.

It's manageable, but a json file would make this a lot easier and straightorward...

My whole code is much longer, split in several classes and files. Please let me know if a part is missing/unclear :smiley:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.